# Spring MVC 3 is there a common place to handle exception and display error message in the same view instead of error page

Tags: spring-mvc, view, exception, return

I am using spring MVC 3.2.4. I have a business exception thrown from business tier and want to display an error message in the same view instead of forwarding to an error page once it is caught. I know I could put try-catch in each handler method and then return to the same view. But I really want a common place to achieve this in Spring MVC. I tried @ExceptionHandler and @ControllerAdvice, It seems not working. 
Here is what I want to do,

```
     @SomeExceptionHandlerAnnation(BusinessException.class)??
     public String handleBusinessException(Model model, 
     BusinessException ex)
     {
        //convertExceptionToMessage();
       //add message to model
       return userView;//stay in the same view
      }
```

The problem is how to get model of the same view. It seems Spring MVC exception handler doesn't support it. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ModelAndView handleAllExceptions(Exception e) {    
      --do something here  
      return new ModelAndView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I want to do is to stay in the same user view. how can I get the model of the user view when I create a new ModelAndView so that the same view will be shown with the same data plus error message?

Comment: It the @ExceptionHandler annotation documentation:           http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html it states that you can sent the request and/or response objects as parameters. You should be able to get the page from where the request was made and go back to it. Give it a shot.